# Install specific Linux kernel headers

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm learning how to write a module, and when I initialize "make", I get

```
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/6.6.6-060606-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

With this Makefile:

```
obj-m = foo.o

KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215054/lib-modules-version-build-not-existent) as a potential solution.
As you can see, I'm running 6.6.6 but Mint only supports an inferior Kernel. Is it okay if I download my latest distro headers and use those?

Answer (score 0):

In terminal

```
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.6.6/amd64/linux-headers-6.6.6-060606-generic_6.6.6-060606.202312111032_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.6.6/amd64/linux-headers-6.6.6-060606_6.6.6-060606.202312111032_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-*.deb
```

Then see if you can compile

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).